# Disable text input for md-chip

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Is there any way by which I can disable the text-input feature for angular material chips?

The `readonly` attribute I found from the documentation seem to disable delete feature as well. I want to keep delete feature intact and disable only the input feature.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how the actual response.
Use attributes:

```
readonly="true" md-removable="true"
```